# Why are women not told to hit their husband?

Tags: women, men, equality

In Islam the men (husbands) are allowed to hit their wife's if they do something which is against Islam. I understand that this does not mean that they can hit hard and it is just a light hit with the edge of a scarf and it is for discipline.

However, my question is that why have women not been told they can hit their husband's if they do something wrong?

Why have only men been given this right?

Answer (score 2):

All praise be to Allah.

> “Men are the protectors and maintainers of women, because Allaah has
>   made one of them to excel the other, and because they spend (to
>   support them) from their means. Therefore the righteous women are
>   devoutly obedient (to Allaah and to their husbands), and guard in the
>   husband’s absence what Allaah order them to guard (e.g., their
>   chastity, their husband’s property, etc.). As to those women on whose
>   part you fear ill-conduct, admonish them (first), (next), refuse to
>   share their beds, (and last) beat them (lightly, if it is useful), but
>   if they return to obedience, seek not against them means (of
>   annoyance). Surely, Allaah is Ever Most High, Most Great.” [al-Nisaa’
>   4:34]

If it is the husband who is mistreating his wife, that does not mean that she should remain oppressed or that her hands are tied. She has the right – just as the husband has – to warn and advise him, and to remind him to fear Allaah. If that does not work, she can seek the help of wise people among his relatives and her own, and they can advise him. If this does not work, then the matter can be taken to a qaadi (Muslim judge) who can force him to do the right thing – and Allaah is above them all.

> When Islam differentiates between the sexes, it is in the interests of both, and this is the essence of wisdom. Unlike a man, a woman does not have to pray and fast when she has her period, out of consideration for her condition.
>   She does not have to spend on her husband, because he is stronger and more able to earn a living. In return, she has to obey him and ask his permission before leaving the house; the reverse does not apply. In the event of a separation, it is the mother, and not the father, who has the right to custody of the children. And there are other rulings which are based on an acknowledgment of the differences between the sexes. Can we then say that this is oppression or unfair discrimination? No, by Allaah, this is justice and wisdom, revealed by the Wise, All-Aware, All-Knowing, All-Seeing.
>
> From this Fatwa [Does a woman have the right to hit her husband if he mistreats her?](https://islamqa.info/en/2083)

Read complete fatwa for more clear picture.

And Allah knows best.

Comment: I understand that but again, if the woman does something haram, the Qur'an give the man the right to hit her lightly but if the husband does something haram the wife can only advise him. Why does the men not only advise or why do the women not get the right to hit too? After all it is the same wrongdoing yet different treatment just because of our gender?

Comment: I think in that fatwa i mentioned you will get all detailed answer to this. If you are not satisfied with this. Than trust your creator that he knows what is good for his creations. Their are certain differences Allah has made between men and women, not just because of gender but because of other many facts. We see in some species that females are more powerful, but for humans, Allah has made men more powerfull physically and head of his home. Besides read full fatwa.

Comment: @Aisha another rather funny reasoning a friend gave me was that if man hits with such light thing, even if women hits back with full strength(because she is angry), its most likely that man will not feel it and will ignore it. But if women were allowed to do so, and man hit back because he is angry, than things can get worse. But i am sure that's not the main reason Allah has allowed only men to hit (although the hitting islam is allowing, like with a miswak or handkerchief, i don't know if it is beating or something else.)

Comment: see also https://sunnah.com/abudawud/39/50

Comment: @Aisha never forget [this](https://sunnah.com/riyadussalihin:278) and [this](https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah:1851) and [this hadith](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:2146)

Answer (score 0):

Because women and men get admonished in different ways. We are not identical.

Additionally, in Islam in every society for every moment you need a leader. For a family it's the father. If the wife isn't happy then she can take it to a higher court (father is *like* a local leader/judge in the house) ie take her case to a religious judge.